# Submitting data through email using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a application that will send emails to users requesting some information to be filled.
The user must be able to fill the informations requested.
What should be the right approach to achieve this ,

A html form should do this or a link should be given to every different user

Comment: i would stick to the link and let them insert the information directly into your application. Parsing the content of emails is to much work and not really stable..

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Email has no interactive capabilities, so you can't embed a form in the email message like you would in a webpage.

A decent solution is to embed a link in the email which takes the user to a page on your app where they can fill in a form and submit the answer to you, like with any webform.

Since you have an email for each user, you could generate the link as `myapp.com/responses/${some_part_dependent_on_email}`. Where the `${some_part_dependent_on_email}` can be a hash of the email or some bijective function of the email. The first option requires that you do a more complex join to find out to which email a response belongs to, whereas the second one might expose users emails in the URLs, which is not so great.